# df command reports that drive is full, even though it is not

Tags: debian, hard-drive, df

When I run `df -h` (Debian 10, 32-bit), I get this:

```
root@valor:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            488M     0  488M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M  5.4M   95M   6% /run
/dev/sda1        54G  1.7G   50G   4% /
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           500M     0  500M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           500M   12K  500M   1% /tmp
folder2ram      500M   21M  480M   5% /var/log
folder2ram      500M     0  500M   0% /var/tmp
folder2ram      500M  268K  500M   1% /var/lib/openmediavault/rrd
folder2ram      500M 1012K  499M   1% /var/spool
folder2ram      500M  6.7M  494M   2% /var/lib/rrdcached
folder2ram      500M  8.0K  500M   1% /var/lib/monit
folder2ram      500M  1.3M  499M   1% /var/cache/samba
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb5       839G  798G     0 100% /srv/dev-disk-by-label-ThasaLOT
```

Note the bottom line.

I've check inodes, and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
root@valor:~# df -i
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             124750   379   124371    1% /dev
tmpfs            127994   574   127420    1% /run
/dev/sda1       3597440 63048  3534392    2% /
tmpfs            127994     1   127993    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            127994    10   127984    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            127994    17   127977    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            127994    16   127978    1% /tmp
folder2ram       127994    66   127928    1% /var/log
folder2ram       127994     5   127989    1% /var/tmp
folder2ram       127994    21   127973    1% /var/lib/openmediavault/rrd
folder2ram       127994    95   127899    1% /var/spool
folder2ram       127994    48   127946    1% /var/lib/rrdcached
folder2ram       127994     4   127990    1% /var/lib/monit
folder2ram       127994     5   127989    1% /var/cache/samba
tmpfs            127994    10   127984    1% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb5      55934976 41245 55893731    1% /srv/dev-disk-by-label-ThasaLOT
```

I've removed LOTS of files from the drive to free space, but it still thinks it's full. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: As of today (Aug 26) I tried to connect it to my Windows computer with LinuxFS by Paragon Software and it worked fine. I was able to add and remove files, and it worked as it should. So now my problem is getting it to work with the Debian machine, because it still doesn't. -_-

Answer (score 1):

You probably still have open files that are marked for deletion when they're closed. Check `lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'` and find the PIDs that are holding open files. If you can HUP the PID, do so. If you can't, you might be able to truncate the file that the PID is holding open with `:> /path/to/open/file`.

If not, you can always schedule a reboot.

Comment: Please see the edit I just made.